# Use HTML5 input[type=file] to upload by different mobile in php, finally type is different

Tags: php, html, input

There is something confusing me. When I use input[type=file] to upload images in different mobile, I get different reponse in the server.

Here is the different response:

***My question is that why i am uploading the image, but I do not get the same response in the server.***

```
<form  action="#" method="post" class='c-image-change-form' enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <!-- <div class="oh jiaBtn active"> -->
            <div class="oh jiaBtn">
                <div class="oh pa">
                    <p id="id_img_list">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="last" id="id_last_img_wrap">
                            <img src="http://cache.hinabian.com/mobile/images/jia3.png" alt="添加照片" />
                            <input name="upfile" type="file" class="file pa" id='id_upfile' accept="image/*" />
                        </a>

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tc imgNum"><span class="color999">最多添加<em>9</em>张照片</span></div>
        </form>
```

> array (
>     'upfile' =>
>     array (
>       'name' => '16460',
>       'type' => 'application/octet-stream',
>       'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpErjuTZ',
>       'error' => 0,
>       'size' => 1627225,
>     ),
>   )
>
> array (   'upfile' =>   array (
>       'name' => 'IMG_20151030_124751.jpg',
>       'type' => 'image/jpeg',
>       'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpOAHfmc',
>       'error' => 0,
>       'size' => 2090488,   ), )

Comment: What makes you think `input type=file` is HTML5?? It's been part of HTML since 1995.

Comment: Is it just the `type=>application/octet-stream` vs `type=>image/jpeg` that is worrying you, or are you expecting the other properties to be the same as well?

Comment: yes,I just want to know that what happen between the type=>application/octet-stream and type=>image/jpeg , or image/png and so on.

Comment: It's just different browsers behaving differently. Nothing you can do about it. You certainly shouldn't rely on the mime type being accurate; it may not be. You should always verify what type of file it is for yourself, without relying on the mime type.

Comment: Hi, Simba. If I am not rely on mimi type , so what I do  to handle this situation.

Comment: It's so weired. I use javascript to extract file's information, such as: $("#input_file').val(); , and I get the value "C:\fakepath\449486'

Comment: Just to be clear, you should **never** rely on anything sent by the browser to be accurate. Always check for yourself in your server-side code. mime type and other header data can be manipulated by hackers. A hacker can easily send you a PHP program or executable file to attack your system, while giving it an "image/jpeg" mime type. It's a very common type of attack. Other header data can also be manipulated, so don't rely on any of them either. You need to load the image file using `imagecreatefromstring()` to verify that it really is an image. Do this regardless of what the mime type says.

Answer (score 0):

// Just use php's function imagecreatefromstring to create a picture, them imagepng ,imagejpg , imagejpeg to save a picture , then use it.

```
private function _imageCreateFromString($data)
{
     $res = imagecreatefromstring($data);
     if($res !== false)
     {
           //header('Content-Type: image/png');
           imagepng($data);
           imagedestroy($res);
     }
}
```